# Extracting min&max in different categories

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract the minimum and maximum level in categories of customer's salary. I have the data set with 1K customers and I matched them to 13 categories regarding their salary: e.g. 'G: 130,000 - 149,999' or 'K: 250,000 - 299,999'. Minimum level for G: 130,000 - 149,999 (column 'min_level') is 130,000 and Maximum level (column 'max_level') is 149,999 for this group. I already figured it out for all numeric categories but I have an issue with ranges: A: below 30,000 (I want to extract the maximum 30K) & L: 300,000 and above (I want to extract the minimum 300K).

My code:

```
select distinct
   cust_income_level,
   substr(cust_income_level, 1, instr(cust_income_level, ' ')) as category,
   substr(cust_income_level, 3, instr(cust_income_level, '-')-4) as min_level,
   substr(cust_income_level, 13, instr(cust_income_level, '-')-3) as max_level
from
    sh.customers
```

```
Result:
cust_income_level   |category| min_level | max_level
G: 130,000 - 149,999|   G:   |  130,000  |  149,999
K: 250,000 - 299,999|   K:   |  250,000  |  299,999
...
A:      Below 30,000|   A:   |  (null)   |   (null)
L: 300,000 and above|   L:   |  (null)   |   (null)
```

Comment: please provide data from the table customer and end result as text, it is so hard to comprehend what you want

Comment: The,maximum of category A may not be 30K, but something lower than that number.

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion you should consider to perform case statement to particular columns:

```
select,
case 
when
substr(cust_income_level,3,7) = '130,000' then 130.000
when 
substr(cust_income_level,9,5) = 'Below' then 0
-- and rest for other min examples as next whens
else ''
end as
min_level


,
case 
when
substr(cust_income_level,13,7) = '149,000' then 149.000
when 
substr(cust_income_level,14,5) = 'above' then 500000000
-- and rest for other max examples as next whens
else ''
end as
max_level
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like here:

```sql
WITH
    income_levels (CUST_INCOME_LEVEL) AS
        (
            SELECT 'A: Below 30,000' From DUAL UNION ALL 
            SELECT 'B: 30,000 - 49,999' From DUAL UNION ALL 
            SELECT 'C: 50,000 - 69,999' From DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 'D: 70,000 - 89,999' From DUAL UNION ALL         
            SELECT 'E: 90,000 - 109,999' From DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 'F: 110,000 - 129,999' From DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 'G: 130,000 - 149,999' From DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 'H: 150,000 - 179,999' From DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 'I: 180,000 - 209,999' From DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 'J: 210,000 - 249,999' From DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 'K: 250,000 - 299,999' From DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 'L: 300,000 and above' From DUAL 
        )
```

... then you should use case expression testing 'below' and 'above' first (CASE exits after first true condition) and then use SubStr in ELSE part.
Here is the code:

```sql
SELECT
    SubStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, 1, 1) "CATEGORY",
    --
    CASE    
        WHEN InStr(Upper(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL), 'BELOW', 1, 1) > 0 THEN Null 
        WHEN InStr(Upper(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL), 'ABOVE', 1, 1) > 0 THEN 300000
    ELSE To_Number(REPLACE(SubStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, InStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, ': ', 1, 1) + 2, (InStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, ' - ', 1, 1) - 1) - (InStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, ': ', 1, 1) + 2) + 1 ), ',','') )
    END "MIN_LEVEL",
    --
    CASE    
        WHEN InStr(Upper(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL), 'BELOW', 1, 1) > 0 THEN 29999 
        WHEN InStr(Upper(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL), 'ABOVE', 1, 1) > 0 THEN Null
    ELSE To_Number(REPLACE(SubStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, (InStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, ' - ', 1, 1) + 4) - 1 ), ',', ''))
    END "MAX_LEVEL"
FROM
    income_levels
```

... which with above sample data results as:

```sql
CATEGORY  MIN_LEVEL  MAX_LEVEL
-------- ---------- ----------
A                        29999 
B             30000      49999 
C             50000      69999 
D             70000      89999 
E             90000     109999 
F            110000     129999 
G            130000     149999 
H            150000     179999 
I            180000     209999 
J            210000     249999 
K            250000     299999 
L            300000
```

Please do your own adjustments of the code if the format of your actual data is in any way different than the one I used here.
If you are not sure about lowest and highest level limits you can get them without hardcoding the numbers (29999 & 300000) if you change the code like below (the result is the same):

```sql
SELECT
    SubStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, 1, 1) "CATEGORY",
    --
    CASE    
        WHEN InStr(Upper(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL), 'BELOW', 1, 1) > 0 THEN Null
        WHEN InStr(Upper(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL), 'ABOVE', 1, 1) > 0 THEN To_Number(REPLACE(SubStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, 4, InStr(UPPER(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL), ' AND', 1, 1) -4), ',', ''))
    ELSE To_Number(REPLACE(SubStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, InStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, ': ', 1, 1) + 2, (InStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, ' - ', 1, 1) - 1) - (InStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, ': ', 1, 1) + 2) + 1 ), ',','') )
    END "MIN_LEVEL",
    --
    CASE    
        WHEN InStr(Upper(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL), 'BELOW', 1, 1) > 0 THEN To_Number(REPLACE(SubStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, InStr(Upper(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL), 'BELOW', 1, 1) + 6), ',', '')) -  1  
        WHEN InStr(Upper(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL), 'ABOVE', 1, 1) > 0 THEN Null
    ELSE To_Number(REPLACE(SubStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, (InStr(CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, ' - ', 1, 1) + 4) - 1 ), ',', ''))
    END "MAX_LEVEL"
FROM
    income_levels
```